# ORM for Ruby that able to generate Model/Migration scripts from existing database

Tags: ruby, orm, sinatra

Is there ORM for Ruby that able to generate Model/Migration scripts from existing database?

i will use it with sinatra.

Comment: Just to check, you mean generate the code for _models_, not scripts for _migrations_?

Comment: umm.. scripts for migrations will also do :3

Comment: What are "Model scripts"?

Comment: Ok, I answered the question wrong because I read "migration" instead of "model", so I'll undelete it now! :)

Comment: @Mladen a ruby class (from ORM) representing each tables

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Sequel's migrations](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/migration_rdoc.html) to dump an existing schema (see "Dumping the current schema as a migration" down the linked page).

Also, I know that if you're on Postgresql or MS SQL Server you can dump the database into scripts, either as a schema or with data too. If the ORM you want to use doesn't have a to-migration facility (or even if it does) you can use those scripts, and even embed them within a migration ([Sequel will accept standard SQL strings too](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html), other ORM's probably can too).

---

Edit: generating models.

If you want to generate models, then Sequel has a [reflection API](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/reflection_rdoc.html). Something like this could get you started:

```
generator = ->(table) {
  s = <<STR
require 'sequel'
class #{table} < Sequel::Model
  # other stuff here
end
STR
}

DB.tables.reject{|name| name == :schema_info }
         .each do |table|
           File.new "app/models/#{table}.rb" do |f|
             f.write generator.call(table)
           end
         end
```

To do the associations would be harder, but I think possible. Take a look at [Database#foreign_key_list](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Database.html#method-i-foreign_key_list) and [Model association basics](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ORM, but there's a very old gem called magic_models which does this, not sure if it still works: http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/